# Why is the option "admin | log entry | Can change log entry" showing?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

What is log entry in the Django admin panel referring to? For example, I am seeing the option of allowing my users to have log entry privileges but I haven't really activated any Logging model (since I don't even know what it does).

However, some might say that this comes pre-installed with Django like Users and Groups does. The difference is that Users and Groups appears by default on my admin panel, so it makes sense to believe that they are pre-installed. I know I am phrasing it kind of weird but I hope you get the point.

Of note I am running Django 1.4.5

Comment: The admin apps logs changes made using the admin interface (the "history" button or the "recent actions" list on admin's root page).

Comment: I have noted I can delete the recent actions, but not edit the logs that appear on history. Where can the user actually change these logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The history is a model that comes with django admin. It uses a generic foreign key so it can log actions for any object.

To view the history of an object click on the edit form, and then click on the history button on the top right. For example, in this screen (from chapter 6 of the [djangobook website](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html)), you can see the history button on a user's edit form.

[image: admin screenshot]

Comment: What about changing the log as a privilege for the user?

Comment: The log is automatically written by django when changes are done via the admin. If you allow users to change the log, then you might as well not keep a log at all. The point of a log is that it cannot be modified by users, only by the system.

For any user that has access to modify objects from the django admin, the log will be written. Try it out yourself by adding a few users as staff and changing any object that is registered with the admin.

Comment: I understand. I am just wondering why Django offers the option that I mention above. It asks me if the user can modify log, however I have not seen where is that even possible.

Comment: It offers this because the logging feature is just like any other application, and they all get a [default set of permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) when you enable authentication.

Comment: Thanks and just to be clear, in a sense the fact that it offers it is misleading since the way logs are setup there is no real changing.